# sum of sigma finite measures

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mu_1, \mu_2$ be $\sigma-$finite measure on $(X, \mathfrak{M})$.

I want to prove that $\mu_1 + \mu_2$ is a $\sigma-$finite on $(X, \mathfrak{M})$.

As $\mu_1$ is $\sigma-$finite, there exists $(A_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\mu_1(X)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_1(A_i)$ with $\mu_1(A_i) < \infty$.

As $\mu_2$ is $\sigma-$finite, there exists $(B_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $\mu_2(X)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu_2(A_i)$ with $\mu_2(A_i) < \infty$

If $C_i = A_i \cap B_i$, $(\mu_1+\mu_2)(C_i) < \infty$, but $\cup_{i=1}^\infty C_i \neq X$, so $C_i$ is not a partition of X.

How can I set $C_i$?

Comment: The idea is correct: Consider the intersection. But try $C_{i,j}=A_i\cap B_j$, for $i,j\in\mathbb N$

Comment: Thank you very much!! I now figured it out.