# Two "simultaneously" sigma-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have two positive $\sigma$-finite measures $\mu$ and  $\lambda$ over the same space $\Omega$.
Thus there exists measurable parts $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ such that

- $\bigcup_nX_n=\Omega$,
- $\bigcup_nY_n=\Omega$,
- $\mu(X_n)<\infty$,
- and $\lambda(Y_n)<\infty$.

But is it possible to find parts $Z_n$ which work "simultaneously" for $\mu$ and $\lambda$ ?

I need measurable parts $(Z_n)$ such that

- $\bigcup_nZ_n=\Omega$,
- $\mu(Z_n)<\infty$,
- $\lambda(Z_n)<\infty$.

The most evident guess $Z_n=X_n\cup Y_n$ does not work because I have no guarantee that $\mu(Y_n)<\infty$.

The second most evident guess $Z_n=X_n\cap Y_n$ may work, but I'm unsure. I cannot prove, for example, that for large enough $n$ we have $X_1\subset Y_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $Z_{m,n}=X_m\cap Y_n$ for all $m,n\geq 1$. Note that $\mathbb{N^2}$ is a countable set, and so $\{Z_{m,n}: m,n\geq 1\}$ is indeed a countable collection, and can be ordered as a sequence. Obviously, all the sets $Z_{m,n}$ are measurable. Also:

$\mu(Z_{m,n})=\mu(X_m\cap Y_n)\leq\mu(X_m)<\infty$

$\lambda(Z_{m,n})=\lambda (X_n\cap Y_n)\leq\lambda(Y_n)<\infty$

And it is easy to check that $\bigcup\limits_{m,n}Z_{m,n}=\Omega$.

Comment: Thanks. Very few after posting I saw [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4142853/sum-of-sigma-finite-measures) giving almost the same answer but with fewer details.